# Best way to return a complex dto in hibernate/jpa method with many data

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a service method:

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public List<DLevelsDTO> getAll(InputDTO json ){
        String idAdminPK = json.getIdAmminstrazionePK();
        Long idAdminPKDecrypted = Long.parseLong(EncrypterUtils.decrypt(idAdminPK));
        
        List<DLevels> entityList = dLevelsRepository.findAll();
        List<DLevelsDTO> resultList = new ArrayList<DLevelsDTO>();
        for(DLevels entity : entityList) {
            
            DLevelsDTO dto = Converter.convert(entity, DLevelsDTO.class);
            
            Optional<List<DUnitEntity>> optHList = dUnitsRepository.findUnit(idAdminPKDecrypted, entity.getCodiLevel());
            
            if (optHList.isPresent()) {
                
                List<DUnitDTO> jsonResponseList = new ArrayList<DUnitDTO>();
                
                List<DUnitEntity> entityHList =optHList.get();
                for(DUnitEntity entityH : entityHList) {
                    DUnitDTO jsonResponse = new DUnitDTO();
                    jsonResponse.setIdUnit(EncrypterUtils.encrypt(entityH.getSequIdUnitaOrganizzativaH()));
                    jsonResponse.setFkAdmin(EncrypterUtils.encrypt(entityH.getFkAdmin().longValue()));
                    jsonResponse.setCodiCodiceUo(entityH.getCodiCodiceUo());
                    jsonResponse.setDescDenomUo(entityH.getDescDenomUo());
                    
                    jsonResponseList.add(jsonResponse);

                }
                dto.setList(jsonResponseList);
            }
            resultList.add(dto);
        }
        return resultList;
    }
```

In first call to a jpa repository ( findAll ) the result length is > 4000 rows
in the for-cycle of this rows, for every one i search another object and also here i have a great amount of data.

The final dto is :

List resultList = new ArrayList() // > 4000 rows

and every object has List entityHList  // > 1000 rows

The time of services response is 10-15 seconds...

There is a best way to decrement a time of service?
If i use an Oracle Table View or Recursive Query instead Java?

Thanks for the response

Comment: can you paginate?

Answer (score 0):

This is best solved with a DTO approach and a dedicated query that does join fetching.

Having said that, I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(DLevels.class)
public interface DLevelsDTO {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();

    // Not sure what the logic is in dUnitsRepository.findUnit()
    @Mapping("units[id = :idAdminPKDecrypted AND codiLevel = VIEW(codiLevel)]")
    List<DUnitDTO> getList();

    @EntityView(DUnitEntity.class)
    public abstract class DUnitDTO {
        private final long sequIdUnitaOrganizzativaH;
        private final long fkAdmin;

        public DUnitDTO(
            @Mapping("sequIdUnitaOrganizzativaH") long sequIdUnitaOrganizzativaH,
            @Mapping("fkAdmin") long fkAdmin
        ) {
            this.sequIdUnitaOrganizzativaH = EncrypterUtils.encrypt(sequIdUnitaOrganizzativaH);
            this.fkAdmin = EncrypterUtils.encrypt(fkAdmin);
        }

        @IdMapping
        public abstract Long getId();
        public abstract String getCodiCodiceUo();
        public abstract String getDescDenomUo();
        public long getSequIdUnitaOrganizzativaH() {
            return sequIdUnitaOrganizzativaH;
        }
        public long getFkAdmin () {
            return fkAdmin;
        }
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`DLevelsDTO a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, DLevelsDTO.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
List<DLevelsDTO> findAll();
```